# installing hector_slam package in fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

How i can installing  [hector_slam  package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot)  in fuerte ... i have searched for it, but i didn't find satisfying results

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54031/installing-hector_slam-package-in-fuerte/) by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-hector-slam
```

should do the trick, provided you are on a platform for which .deb based ROS packages are available.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3